# Razor Pages .Net Core: Opening a new tab/window from OnPost

Tags: .net-core, razor-pages

How can a new tab or window be opened from an OnPost method within a model class?  I am trying to return a FileStreamResult to a new tab and reload the page on the current tab.

Comment: What have you tried? This should/could be done in javascript.

Comment: I am trying to open a PDF that is generated using FileStream.  I return the FileStreamResult in the OnPost, which opens the PDF in the browser.  I want to be able to return the FileStreamResult to a new tab and return Page on the current tab.  I tried using Javascript. It forces me to fetch the PDF after it has been created and that gives me the error "Not allowed to load loacal resource."